# How can I make a list that can be accesed by other classes?

Tags: c++, list, class, stl

I'm trying to make a project using the standard `std::list`. There is a list of names that have to be accessed by multiple classes. The list has to be inside a class. I'm currently trying with this code:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    list<string> myList =  {"one","two","three"};

public:
    list<string> GetList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
};
```

The class that I want to access the list from

```
class CallingClass {

    MyClass myClass;

public:
    void GetList()
    {
        list<string> calledList = myClass.GetList();
        for(int x=0;x<4;x++) { 
            cout<<calledList[x]<<endl; // I get error in this line: "no match for operator[]"
        }
    }
};
```

main

```
int main()
{
    CallingClass call;
    call.GetList();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: Tactical note: If you had clarified the previous question rather than making a new one, you would only have two poorly received questions instead of three. Take care because if you ask too many questions that are not seen as positive contributions by the community you will find the rate at which you can ask questions drops dramatically, eventually restricting you to one question ever six months or so.

Comment: In other words, learn how to ask good questions up front, and if they still get closed, at least fix them so they can be reopened. Don't just abandon them and repost them again.

Comment: Additional note: The server remembers everything and uses deleted questions in its computations on when to let you ask new questions. The algorithm is a company secret, but my understanding is that deleted content is weighted more harshly than  mere downvotes and a deleted post cannot be re-evaluated since it is no longer visible to the community. Once you post something, you're stuck with it, so it is in your best interests to attempt to repair before deleting.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> for(int x=0;x<4;x++) { 
>     cout<<calledList[x]<<endl;
> }
> ```

There are two problems with this `for` loop:

- the returned `std::list` only has 3 elements, but you are trying to access 4 elements, so the last iteration of the loop would go out of bounds, which is *undefined behavior*.
- Not that it matters, because `std::list` does not have an `operator[]` defined to begin with, which is what the compiler is warning you about.  This is because `std::list` is not a random-access container, like `std::vector` is, so you can't access its elements by index.  You have to walk through the `std::list` using iterators instead.

Try this:

```
list<string>::iterator iter = calledList.begin();
for(size_t x = 0; x < calledList.size(); x++) { 
    cout << *iter << endl;
    ++iter;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
for(list<string>::iterator iter = calledList.begin(); iter != calledList.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

Which can then be simplified further by using a [`range-for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop (in C++11 and later), which internally handles the iterators for you:

```
for(auto &elem : calledList) { 
    cout << elem << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with what classes wants to access from which other class. It is something more fundamental.

```
cout<<calledList[x]<<endl;
```

`calledList` is a `std::list`. `std::list`s do ***not*** have an overloaded `[]` operator. Only `std::vector`s do. Either replace your lists with vectors, or use some other way to iterate over a list. How about range iteration, using modern C++?

```
for (auto &l : calledList)
   cout << l << endl;
```

Furthermore:

```
for(int x=0;x<4;x++) {
```

Even if you could use `[]` with a `list`, you have another problem. The loop will end up accessing the first four values in the container. The shown container only has three values. This will result in undefined behavior.

To summarize:

1. `std::list`s do not have `[]` operators.
2. Using range iteration, and modern C++, results in safer and more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two other answers that explain your problem. I'm going to point out one more thing:

```
    const list<string> & GetList()
    {
        return myList;
    }
    ...
    const list<string> & calledList = myClass.GetList();
```

I made very slight changes. Your version returns a COPY of your list. This is inefficient. instead, you should return a const reference. Notice I added the `const` keyword and the `&` character.

And then when I use it, I also made the list a const reference.

Now, if you actually need a COPY, you can still do this:

```
list<string> calledList = myClass.GetList();
```

This will end up doing the same thing as your version. But most of the time, you are only going to read the list in some sort of const fashion, so you save a lot of work by returning a const reference and then assigning it to a const reference.

Comment: Since you are returning a const reference, you should declare `GetList()` itself as `const`, too: `const list<string>& GetList() const`. Actually, even in the version that returns a copy, `GetList()` should still be `const`: `list<string> GetList() const`